# why is my @EJB not getting injected to my web service?

Tags: eclipse, ejb, websphere, jax-rs

I have a basic EJB 3.0 (Java EE 5) project in IBM RAD (aka Eclipse 3.4) and WebSphere 7.0

I created an EAR project, an EJB project (for the EJBs), a JPA project (for the domain objects), and a Dynamic Web project (for my JAX-RS web service).

The EJB project contains an EJB like so:

```
@Stateless
public TestBean implements TestBeanLocal { 
/* ... */

@Local
public TestBeanLocal {
/* ... */
```

The Web project contains a JAX-RS web service like so:

```
@Path(value="/mywebservice")
public MyWebService implements Application {
  @EJB
  private TestBeanLocal myBean;

  @GET
  @Produces({"text/plain"})
  public String getList() {
    return myBean.getList();
    /* ... */
```

My problem is the "myBean" attribute in MyWebService is never injected.  It's always null.

Any ideas what I missed?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: WebSphere 7.0 doesn't provide JAX-RS support out of the box. What framework (or WebSphere feature pack) are you using as JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: I'm using Apache Wink 1.0 which is what they use in the JAX-RS tutorial that's in the IBM RAD help docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java EE container will only perform @EJB injection on components it manages. For Java EE 5, this would include servlets, Web services and EJBs. In your case the component is managed by Wink, so the question is whether Wink is expected to interpret @EJB (I guess not). With Java EE 6 injection works because JAX-RS is part of that Java EE version and the component is managed by the container, not by a 3rd party framework.

Answer (score 0):

After much hair-pulling, I created a clean new project (the following has slightly different classnames) ... I noticed in WebSphere's start up log the EJB had the JNDI name, so I tried looking up the EJB by it's JNDI in the constructor of the web service ...

```
String sJNDI = "ejblocal:testEAR/testEJB.jar/TestBean#test.TestBeanLocal";
TestBeanLocal testBeanLocal = (TestBeanLocal) new InitialContext().lookup(sJNDI);
```

... and that worked.

My question now is, do I really have to do this to see my beans?  Or is there something I missed?  On another project using a Java EE 6 version of GlassFish all I had to do was put in @EJB and it was fine.  Does that simply not work in Java EE 5 / WebSphere 7?  Or maybe it's a limitation of IBM RAD 7 (aka Eclipse 3.4)?

Thanks,
Rob